# DRYing code resulted in doubling output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am making a resume application to list my employment history, education history and other responsibilities. This is my first rails application on my own without a tutorial, but much of what I do is just following the same actions. All the code is here: https://github.com/victorman/portfolio

Quick summary. I ajaxed my app a bit, and got it to work. But I had a template with the exact same html as part of a view, so I replaced that portion with a `render :partial...`. The result was twice the html as before. Below is a more detailed description of what I did to the app.

---

I made two scaffolds, one for Jobs and one for Categories. Jobs has a foreign key to categories.

I made the Jobs view list a link for each category. The `jobs#index` controller then only finds the rows in the jobs table for that category.

Then I decided to throw some ajax in there so that clicking a link would only reload the relevant data. I added a respond_to at the end of the `jobs#index` method.

```
def index
  #find which jobs to display based on category_id in the url params
  #if no category_id param is given default to 1
  unless params.has_key? :category_id
    @jobs = Job.find(:all, :conditions => {:category_id => 1})
  else
    @jobs = Job.find(:all, :conditions => {:category_id => params[:category_id]})
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js    #index.js.erb
  end
end
```

I made a index.js.erb file that retrieves the new data and replaces the old.

```
var jobs = $("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @jobs))%>").hide();
$("#jobs_table").replaceWith(jobs);
$("#jobs_table").fadeIn();
```

I added remote: true to the links in the jobs index.html.erb file.

```
<ul>
    <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
    <li><%= link_to category.name, { :controller => "jobs", :category_id => "#{category.id}" }, :class => "category_link", remote: true %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

And I made the template partial where the jobs were displayed. it would never find _jobs.html.erb so i had to name it `_job.html.erb`

```
<tbody id="jobs_table">
  <% @jobs.each do |job| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= job.organization %></td>
      <td><%= job.location %></td>
      <td><%= job.details %></td>
      <td><%= job.start_date %></td>
      <td><%= job.end_date %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', job %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_job_path(job) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', job, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

after all that it worked but I still hadn't DRY'd up the code so I removed the repeated section from `index.html.erb` which is in `_job.html.erb` (as shown above) and replaced it with this.

```
<%= render :partial => @jobs %>
```

and now it gives me two identical `<tbody>` tags with id="jobs_table". Why is this giving duplicate data?

[image: two tbody tags. guess where I live.]

Comment: Did my answer help you in any way?

Comment: they do not appear to have fixed the bug. https://github.com/victorman/portfolio/commit/2a47305d3f82000c9c75f8b8effc32fd67ee74f0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to not understanding when rails manipulates singular vs plural.

Calling `render partial: @jobs` automagically goes out to the partial _job.html.erb for each element in `@jobs`. But then the partial goes through each element again because of `@jobs.each do |job|`.

To fix it, in the render line, replace `@jobs` with `"jobs"` and rename _job.html.erb to _jobs.html.erb.
Alternatively, save a step by just replacing `@jobs` with `"job"` and keep the template name _job, but this reinforces an incorrect naming scheme.

index.html.erb:

```
<tbody id="jobs"><%= render partial: "jobs" %></tbody>
```

index.js.erb:

```
$("#jobs").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'jobs'))%>")
```

Now it will just search literally for the _jobs template (_jobs.html.erb) and render it once as opposed to going to the singular version of the name and rendering that many times.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a lot to fix...
Create a nested route in your routes.rb:

```
resources :jobs
resources :categories do
  resources :jobs
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Listing jobs</h1>
<div>
  <ul>
    <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
      <li><%= link_to category.name, category_jobs_path(category), 
                class: "category_link", remote: true %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Organization</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Details</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>End date</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="jobs_table"><%= render partial: @jobs %></tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<%= link_to 'New Job', new_job_path %>
```

the index of jobs_controller.rb can (should) be refactored to:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @jobs = Job.where(category_id: params[:category_id] || 1)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

and the index.js.erb response also should be refactored to:

```
$("#jobs_table").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: @jobs) %>")
$("#jobs_table").fadeIn()
```

there are some naming issues which should be more pregnant like:

**jobs** instead of jobs_table
and
**category** instead of category_link
Also trying to find a Job belonging to Category with 1 is odd. Deal with a different response than a default Category with id 1 (hard coded ids are one of the worst things you can do).
The div around the Categories list is useless (keep your rendered HTML slim and readable).